# Como pegar a data atual e adicionar "n" minutos neste valor?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Eu consigo pegar a data atual simplesmente com `new Date()`, mas como faço para adicionar uma quantidade de minutos a este valor? Se houver uma forma para adicionar milissegundos, pode ser também.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
var data = new Date(),
    minutos = 3;

data.setMinutes(data.getMinutes() + minutos);
```

Comment: Existem outros métodos desse tipo para outras unidades? Tipo para segundos ou então para dias.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Voce poder ver os otros métodos no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter).

Answer (score 3):

Tenta:

`var novaData = new Date(velhaData.getTime() + diff*60000);`

Onde `diff` é a diferença em minutos.

Answer (score 3):

É muito difícil fazer muitas coisas com o objeto `Date`. Se você quiser mais controle, considere a ferramenta [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Por exemplo, para adicionar 5 minutos:

```js
moment.add("minutes", 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você tem um objeto Date, chamando o método `getTime` você tem a representação dessa data em milesegundos desde 01/01/1970. O construtor do tipo Date aceita que você passe um parâmetro representando milesegundos desde essa data inicial até a data que você deseja, se você não passar nada ele pega a data atual.

Então você pode criar uma função que pega a sua data, o valor em minutos e realiza a adição usando essa ideia dos milesegundos no construtor.

```
function adicionarMinutos(data, minutos) {
     return new Date(data.getTime() + minutos * 60000);
}
```

Essa multiplicação por 60000 é para converter minutos para milesegundos. Você pode fazer o mesmo tipo de função para adicionar dias, meses, segundos, etc, lembrando sempre de converter o dado desejado para milesegundos.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dtInicio = new Date();
var dtFinal = new Date();
dtFinal.setMinutes(dtInicio.getMinutes()+30);
```