# Preciso saber como passar valor para funções Dates() em JavaScript de preferencia passar minutos

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso saber como passar valor para funções Dates() em JavaScript de preferencia passar minutos?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>contagem regressiva</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
          a= new Date.getMinutes();
          console.log(a)   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vc quer fazer oq, pegar os minutos da hora atual do sistema?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar a data atual e adicionar "n" minutos neste valor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2766/como-pegar-a-data-atual-e-adicionar-n-minutos-neste-valor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja por gentileza se desta forma ajuda.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function time()
{
today=new Date();
h=today.getHours();
m=today.getMinutes();
s=today.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
setTimeout('time()',500);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="time()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```